# How to upgrade spree3-0stable to 3-1stable branch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, spree

My requirement is to upgrade spree version from 3-0 stable to 3-1 stable.

My current gemfile has::

```
gem 'rails', '4.2.2'
gem 'spree', '~> 3.0.8'
gem 'spree_gateway', '~> 3.0.0'
gem 'spree_auth_devise', '~> 3.0.0'
gem 'spree_static_content', github: 'spree-contrib/spree_static_content', branch: '3-0-stable'
gem 'spree_slider', github: 'spree-contrib/spree_slider', branch: '3-0-stable'
gem 'spree_mail_settings', github: 'spree-contrib/spree_mail_settings', branch: '3-0-stable'
gem 'spree_multi_currency', github: 'spree/spree_multi_currency', branch: '3-0-stable'
gem 'spree_paypal_express', github: 'spree-contrib/better_spree_paypal_express', branch: '3-0-stable'
gem 'spree_editor', github: 'spree-contrib/spree_editor', branch: '3-0-stable'
```

so for upgrading spree I have updated my gemfile with given code:

```
gem 'rails', '~> 4.2.6'
gem 'spree', '~> 3.0.7'
gem 'spree_auth_devise', '~> 3.0.5'
gem 'spree_gateway', '~> 3.0.0'
gem 'spree_static_content', github: 'spree-contrib/spree_static_content', branch: '3-1-stable'
gem 'spree_slider', github: 'spree-contrib/spree_slider', branch: '3-1-stable'
gem 'spree_mail_settings', github: 'spree-contrib/spree_mail_settings', branch: '3-1-stable'
gem 'spree_multi_currency', github: 'spree/spree_multi_currency', branch: '3-1-stable'
gem 'spree_paypal_express', github: 'spree-contrib/better_spree_paypal_express', branch: '3-0-stable'
gem 'spree_editor', github: 'spree-contrib/spree_editor', branch: '3-1-stable'
```

after that I run bundle update command

I face given error ::
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "spree_backend":

> In Gemfile:
>       spree was resolved to 3.1.1.beta, which depends on
>         spree_backend (= 3.1.1.beta)
>
> ```
> spree_editor was resolved to 3.0.5, which depends on
>   spree_backend (~> 3.0.0)
>
> spree_mail_settings was resolved to 3.1.0, which depends on
>   spree_backend (~> 3.1.0.beta)
>
> spree_mail_settings was resolved to 3.1.0, which depends on
>   spree_backend (~> 3.1.0.beta)
>
> spree_slider was resolved to 3.1.0, which depends on
>   spree_backend (>= 3.1.0.beta)
> ```

Please guide me how to upgrade and resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `3-0-stable` branch for each spree extension as you are using 3.0.x spree version.

Else use spree version 3.1.x and use 3-1-stable branch for spree extensions.

Comment: Any idea on how to upgrade from 2-3 stable to current stable version of spree i.e. 3-1 stable.

Comment: Thats gonna be tough. I would suggest to take baby steps for this.
Get you specs ready. Upgrade to 2-4-stable. Stabilise specs. Upgrade to 3-0-stable. Stabilise specs. Upgrade to 3-1-stable.